# Find all complex numbers $z$ such that $| z | = 1$ and $ |\frac z {\overline z} + \frac {\bar z} z | = 1. $

Tags: complex-numbers

*My friend and I came across such a question about complex numbers. We know the solution $( \frac1z + \frac1z =1)$ of this and we know that we need to solve it with x+yi but we are stuck on this question, can you help us?*

The question is asking us exactly that:

Find all complex numbers $z$ such that $| z | = 1$ and $ |\frac z {\overline z}  +  \frac {\bar z} z  | = 1. $

Comment: If $|z|=1$ then you can write $z=e^{i \theta}$ which makes this problem much simpler if you know how to write trig functions as a sum of complex exponentials.

Comment: For $|z|=1$, the other equation is equivalent to $|z^2+\overline z^2|=1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Generalization**:

Let $z=r(\cos t+i\sin t)$ where $r>0$ and $t$ is real

$\dfrac z{\bar z}=\cos2t+i\sin2t$

$\iff \dfrac{\bar z}z=\cos2t-i\sin2t$

$\implies|2\cos2t|=1\implies\cos2t=\pm\dfrac12$

$\implies\cos4t=\cdots=-\dfrac12=\cos120^\circ$

$\implies4t=360^\circ n\pm120^\circ$   where $n$ is any integer

$\iff t=?$ where $0\le n\le3$

So, we have $4+4$ in-congruent solutions

Comment: thank you very much(:

Answer (score 1):

Much like @Lab Bhattacharjee’s answer, but cast in geometric language.

Zero’th, if $w$ is a complex number, then $w+\overline w$ is real, twice the real part of $w$.

First, to require $|z|=1$ is to put $z$ on the unit circle.

Second, for points $z$ on the unit circle, $\overline z=1/z$, so that for our points, $z/\overline z=z^2$ and $\overline z/z={\overline z}^2=\overline{z^2}$.

Third, the second condition therefore says that $2\Re(z^2)=1$ or $2\Re(z^2)=-1$.

If we call $\xi$ the primitive twelfth root of unity $\cos\frac\pi6+i\sin\frac\pi6$, then the first  possibility in (3) above is $z=\pm\xi$ or $z=\pm\xi^{11}$; the second possibility above is $\xi=\pm\xi^2$ or $\pm\xi^4$.

In other words, $z$, as a number on the clock-face of the unit circle, lies at hours 1,2,4,5,7,8,10,11.

Answer (score 0):

For $|z|=1$, the second equation is equivalent to $|z^2+\overline z^2|=1$. With $z=x+iy$, the first equation (squared) is $x^2+y^2=1$ and the second is $2(x^2-y^2)=\pm1$, or, on substituting $y^2=1-x^2$,

$$x^2={1\over2}\left(1\pm{1\over2}\right)$$

hence

$$x=
\begin{cases}
\pm\displaystyle{1\over2}\\
\pm\displaystyle{\sqrt3\over2}
\end{cases}$$

In all, there are eight solutions:

$$z=\pm{1\over2}\pm{\sqrt3\over2}i\quad\text{and}\quad z=\pm{\sqrt3\over2}\pm{1\over2}i$$

with all four combinations of signs in each case.

Comment: thank you very much (: